# Django load objects instances just once, make them available starting app

Tags: python, django

I have an app (Django 1.6) that uses around 4000 objects, for natural language processing (NLP), previously generated.

All application processes (requests, tests, custom management commands, etc) need to use all of those objects in some way.

What I'd like to do is to load all of those objects, just once, at the startup moment (or so), and store them in memory to make them available for all app processes.

This [post](http://eldarion.com/blog/2013/02/14/entry-point-hook-django-projects/) has some clues but I'd love to hear your thoughts about what is the best approach to the situation.

**Clarification**: The 4000 objects are used just for reading in all processes, they are not being modified in any way into the app.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to put all the data into the [cache](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/cache/) and also take advantage of Memcached cache backend. So the data could be fast, safely and easily accessed by any of your processes.

Comment: It's a good option @isobolev. I'll check it. Thank you very much.

Comment: Caching can be tricky in this scenario. If these are large objects, deserializing them back from the cache each time can possibly be a very expensive operation. It might even be worse than just having a single copy ready to go in the project settings once per process.

Comment: @YuvalAdam has a good point. Test this option is relatively simple, so I'll share with you how it behaves.

Answer (score 0):

The best idea in this situation is probably to launch a dedicated process just for this stuff. Any other way and your objects are not guaranteed to be single across your deployment cluster.

If you are deploying using separate process workers you will have several different copies of your NLP data (one per process), and if you're deploying using cooperative threads (such as when using gunicorn gevent workers) then you have to make sure your code is thread-safe.

I would set up this as an external service running on a dedicated process, and have each client access this service using your choice of intra-process communication (sockets, HTTP, whatever).

For local development, testing purposes and ease of deployment you can always fall back to loading these objects into your projects settings.

Comment: Perhaps the objects don't need to be mutated.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @yuval-adam. Loading the objects in settings is exactly what I'm doing until now for development. Based on paul-draper comment, I did a clarification about the use of the objects. I'll research a little about your option to have it as an external service, however, ideally I'd want to maintain the objects into the app.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Redis. The [python client](https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py) works well and maybe you can even use [rom](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/rom) which seems nice for modeling your data. Disclaimer: I've used Redis before but I've never used rom, I just found it a couple of days ago and I thought it was worth sharing it.

Good luck!

Comment: Hey @jcatalan, thank you so much for the suggestion. My first option is to have the objects into the same app, however if this not work, a key-value store is definitively something to keep in mind. BTW: I didn't know about rom.